# Transfom file path into Ruby nested Class using regex syntax transform

Tags: regex, vscode-snippets

I try to change this (VSCode `RELATIVE_FILEPATH` variable):

`app/service/namespace/important_thing/my_class.rb`

into this:

`Namespace::ImportantThing::MyClass`

What I got so far:

```
RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(?:\\/?app\\/\\w+)?(\\/|_)(.(?!\\w+?\\.rb))/::${2:/upcase}/g}:
```

but the result is not great

`::Namespace::Importand::Thing/my_class.rb`

I'm doing this to create myself a snippet but this regex is a little bit to much for me.

I've used something similar in Sublime but there it was done with some code in python so can't be referenced from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
"${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/^(?:.*?[\\\\\\/])?app[\\\\\\/]\\w+[\\\\\\/]|([^\\\\\\/]+?)(?:\\.rb$|([\\\\\\/]))/${1:/pascalcase}${2:+::}/g}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KOMyee/2). *Details*:

- `^(?:.*?[\\\/])?app[\\\/]\w+[\\\/]` - start of string, any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, then `\` or `/`, then an `app`, a `\` or `/`, one or more word chars, `\` or `/`
- `|` - or
- `([^\\\/]+?)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `\` and `/` as few as possible
- `(?:\.rb$|([\\\/]))` - a non-capturing group matching either `.rb` at the end of string, or `\` / `/` (captured into Group 2).

The replacement is `${1:/pascalcase}${2:+::}`:

- `${1:/pascalcase}` - replace the match with Group 1 turned into PasCal case
- `${2:+::}` - if Group 2 matched, also add `::` to the replacement.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. The explanations also allowed me to learn something new! I was able to modify it and also use it in my _spec.rb files templates.